# Issue in AES encryption for android - dev vs release build using react-native-crypto-js package

Tags: android, react-native, encryption, cryptojs, node-crypto

```
import CryptoJS from "react-native-crypto-js";

//encryption function used in react native code base

export const encryptValue = (text) => {

try {

        const key = 'J4f9eO8ayjjEtamRBxSSmsDqXBele1zl'
        const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8)
        let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            text, key, {
                keySize: 16,
                iv: iv,
            });
        let v = { iv: iv.toString(), encryptedData: encrypted.toString() }
        return v
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error - ', error)
    }
}

const crypto = require('crypto-js')

//decryption function used in server - node

export const decrypt = (data) => {


try {

        let key = "J4f9eO8ayjjEtamRBxSSmsDqXBele1zl"
        let decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt(
            data.encryptedData, key, {
                keySize: 16,
                iv: data.iv
            }).toString(crypto.enc.Utf8)
        console.log('decrypted - ', decrypted)
        return decrypted.toString()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err)
    }

}
```

Above code encryption and decryption works fine for android debug build and server side code. However, Android build generated in release.. generates encrypted text, but does not decrypt at server.

Comment: Can you show us the output of each of the commands with some test data to encrypt.  It will also be useful if you can show us the raw value of your IV.

Comment: Same thing in iOS release.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Facing the same issue. How come you resolved this!?

Answer (score 0):

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

    export const encryptValue = (text) => {
        try {
            const key = 'AbcdefghtkmacweBczaOaDMaDCaf1wqs'
            const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8)
            let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
                text, key, {
                keySize: 16,
                iv: iv,
            });
            let v = { iv: iv.toString(), encryptedData: encrypted.toString() }
            return v
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error - ', error)
        }
    }
    
    
    export const decrypt = (data) => {
        try {
            let key = "AbcdefghtkmacweBczaOaDMaDCaf1wqs"
            let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                data.encryptedData, key, {
                keySize: 16,
                iv: data.iv
            }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
            return decrypted.toString()
        } catch (err) {
           console.log('err', err)
        }
    }
```

This solution worked for me.